# how to remove headers from a tabular image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I need to remove first row (headers in this example) from a tabular image, using simple numpy functions or some image filtering

[image: input]

I want to get this output:

[image: output]

Comment: you can do it by summing the columns and then looking for the row at which the values drop. use the row index you find this way to extract the bottom part of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the solution I've made to solve this issue.

```py
import cv2

def crop (image):
    '''
    remove additional upper lines from tabular image
    :param image: image to crop
    :return: image cropped
    '''

    # Load image, convert to grayscale, Otsu's threshold

    result = image.copy()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    # Detect horizontal lines
    horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (40,1))
    detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnts[-1])

    height, width = image.shape[:2]
    crop_img = image[y+h+2:height,0:width]
    return crop_img


image = cv2.imread('k.png')
cropped_img = crop(image)
cv2.imshow("cropped", cropped_img)
cv2.imwrite("o.png", cropped_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function   selectROI()

```
cv2.namedWindow('ROI') 
r=cv2.selectROI('ROI', img,False,False)
# cut rectangle
imROI = img[int(r[1]):int(r[1]+r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0]+r[2])]
cv2.destroyWindow('ROI')
cv2.imshow("ROI", imROI)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I don't recommend this method, cropping image manually lacks precision